# Resize form element without displacing the text

Tags: sketch-app

Trying to resize a text field in Sketch App. Every time the text shifts to the right. Similar things happens when I resize the checkbox text, the square resizes too.

Text has extra space to the left when I extend the textbox

[image]

Square is misshapen when I extend the text

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to enter the group and resize only the object that you want to resize (keep double-clicking until you get to the object, or you can select the object in the left sidebar).

Another solution, possible only with Sketch 39 and above, is to create a symbol out of the textbox with text and out of the checkbox with a label. Set the checkbox's resize mode to "Pin to corner". For the text labels, make them take up the whole size they can take up in the symbol and set their resize mode to "Resize object".